# как задать уникальные пары столбцев в миграции Yii2?

Tags: yii2, миграция

Каждый элемент первого столбца, относится к нескольким элементам второго столбца. Таблица имеет следующий вид:

```
+-------------------+------------------+
|    1 столбец      |     2 столбец    |
+-------------------+------------------+
|       1           |          a       |
+-------------------+------------------+
|       1           |          b       |
+-------------------+------------------+
|       1           |          c       |
+-------------------+------------------+
|       2           |          d       |
+-------------------+------------------+
|       2           |          a       |
+-------------------+------------------+
```

Как сделать так, чтоб пары были уникальными? Чтоб при вводе, случайно не появилась еще одна пара 2-d. Оба столбца не уникальны.
Цель - сократить количество запросов, что , по моему мнению, должно ускорить работу.
Примерно вот так должен выглядеть запрос итоговый:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE `INDEX_NAME` ( `field1` , `field2` )
```

Comment: ... PRIMARY KEY (`field1`, `field2`)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: Нее, миграция в yii2… это-то понятно...

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->createTable('{{%table}}', [
    'field1' => $this->integer(),
    'field2' => $this->string(),
    'PRIMARY KEY (`field1`, `field2`)'
]);
```